# ¿Porque la función strtok() no funciona como deseo en C?

Tags: base-de-datos, c, archivo, crud, cuenta-usuario

estoy haciendo una función para consultar si existe el nombre de algún usuario en un fichero e imprimir en pantalla lo que hay debajo de su nombre linea por linea hasta que haya una que tenga un "-", hace rato lo probé y estaba funcionando, pero después empezó a imprimir todo hasta el final del archivo sin tomar en cuenta que en alguna linea haya un "-":

```
int consultarUsuario(){
system("cls");
char palabra[100],buffer[100], bufer[100];
int usEx=0;
printf("ingresa el nombre de usuario\n");
scanf("%s", palabra);
FILE *f;
f = fopen("./db_boletos/baseprueba.dat", "r");

while (feof(f)==0)      
{
    fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
    if (strcmp(palabra,buffer)==0)      
    {
        printf("%s%s%s\n", "EL BOLETO DEL USUARIO USUARIO ", buffer, " TIENE LO SIGUIENTE: ");
        usEx=1;
        while (fgets(bufer, 100, f))
        {               
            strtok(bufer, "-");
            printf("%s", bufer);
        }
        
        break;
    }
    
}
if(usEx==0){
    printf("%s%s%s", "el usuario ", palabra, " no existe");
    
}
fclose(f);
```

}

Mi archivo se ve de esta forma:

```
jesus
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 4
TOTAL A PAGAR: 800.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 128.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200
-
jesus2
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 4
TOTAL A PAGAR: 800.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 128.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200
-
```

por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa "jesus", me gustaría que solo imprima

```
jesus
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 4
TOTAL A PAGAR: 800.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 128.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200
-
```

pero imprime:

```
jesus
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 4
TOTAL A PAGAR: 800.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 128.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200
-
jesus2
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 4
TOTAL A PAGAR: 800.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 128.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200
-
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué supones que hace `strtok()`? Su función no es comprobar si una cadena o carácter forma parte de otra, para eso debes usar `strstr()`, por ejemplo `if strstr(buffer, "-")`

Comment: ya intenté con eso, pero no funciona
`while (feof(f)==0)  
 {
  fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
  if (strcmp(palabra,buffer)==0)  
  {
   printf("%s%s%s\n", "EL BOLETO DEL USUARIO USUARIO ", buffer, " TIENE LO SIGUIENTE: ");
   usEx=1;
   while (fgets(bufer, 100, f))
   {    
    //strtok(bufer, "-");
    if (strstr(buffer, "-")){
     break;
    }
    printf("%s", bufer);
    
   }
   
   
   
   break;
  }
  
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `strtok()` no es para determinar si una subcadena (en este caso "-") aparece dentro de otra, sino para dividir una cadena por los puntos en que otra aparezca.

Para mirar si una cadena aparece dentro de otra la función sería `strstr()`. No obstante en este caso esa función tampoco nos sirve porque el `"-"` de hecho aparece en otros lugares aparte del "marcador de fin de registro". Por ejemplo aparece en las horas: `"10:00am-13:00pm"`

En realidad es mucho más sencillo (en este caso) mirar si la primera letra del `bufer` es el signo `-`. Esto puede hacerse así (limito el código a la parte relevante):

```
      if (strcmp(palabra,buffer)==0)      
      {
          printf("%s%s%s\n", "EL BOLETO DEL USUARIO USUARIO ", buffer, " TIENE LO SIGUIENTE: ");
          usEx=1;
          while (fgets(bufer, 100, f))
          {               
              if (bufer[0]=='-') break;
              printf("%s", bufer);
          }
          break;      
      }
```

Como ves, basta comparar `bufer[0]` con `'-'` (atención a usar aquí comillas simples, pues estamos comparando con un carácter y no con una cadena).